# Bigquery JOIN optimization

Tags: google-bigquery

We are running a query every 5 minutes with a JOIN. On one side of the JOIN is table1@time1-time2 (as we only look at the incremental part), another side of the JOIN is table2, which keeps changing as we are stream data into it. The JOIN is now like

```
[table1@time1-time2] AS T1 INNER JOIN EACH table2 AS T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```

Since every time this query involves the whole T2, is there any possible optimization I can do, such as using cache or else, in order to minimize the money cost?

**EDIT**
The query:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the full query?

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting text would be better, hard to read the query on that screenshot.

That said, I see a SELECT * for the second table. Selecting only the needed columns would only query a fraction of the table, instead of all of it.

Also, why are you generating a row_in and joining on a different one?

Comment: I feel a row_id is necessary for row_rum() to partition on. But it's not the actual key linking two sides of JOIN. But this makes me think that probably row_id for t_gps is not necessary.